# Unable to connect to my remote desktop

Tags: linux, networking, router, remote-desktop, mysql

I want to remotely access my desktop PC (server) that has a static IP, from my laptop. Both are running Linux Mint 21.2.

I have opened the port 3306 on my router settings because I want to access a MySQL database.
If I try to `ping x.xxx.xxx.xx` or either use `tracepath x.xxx.xxx.xx 3306` or `telnet x.xxx.xxx.xx` commands it won't reach it. Same trying to access the database.

I checked if there is a firewall active in the server using `ufw status`, but it's inactive.
I don't know where the problem may be, but it seems something blocking the connection on the server side.

Comment: Is it on the local network or the internet? For the internet, have you forwarded the the port to your computer? What do you mean that your PC has a static address, from your ISP?

Comment: Yes exactly from my ISP. I'm quite a newbie so pardon me, I have forwarded the 3306 Port on my router settings, then if I try on the server **netstat -nltp** I get
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN `  as output. Shall this means is it correctly forwarded?

Comment: Are you trying from the local network to access another computer in the same local network via the internet? Most consumer routers do not support it.

Comment: No I have my laptop in Portugal now, and my server is in Italy.

Comment: I asked other people I know to reach this IP from Italy with the same results. So I guess it's a server problem. Plus if I use tracepath I can see that the route goes almost till the server and then stops.

Comment: Which remote access software are you using for server and client?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147658/discussion-between-zep-and-harrymc).

Comment: `Shall this means is it correctly forwarded?` no, it means something is listening on port 3306 ... the fact that you mention "forwarded" suggests your server is behind a NAT router, i.e. it does not have a public IP address, so you need to forward port 3306 on your router from WAN to the appropriate LAN IP address of your server

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did exactly this. From my router admin page, on the "Port Triggering" section, I triggered the port 3306 with the internal IP of my device associated. But I want to stress that I feel it's something like a firewall that is blocking the connection, but I'm not able to find what...

Comment: Has your problem been served?

Comment: No I solved uploading the database in a host site and accessing through this server. 
To this day I still don't know what's blocking the connection to my remote desktop PC.
I called both TPLink experts and my ISP customer service and they couldn't find where is the problem.
For sure I learned many things about networks!

Comment: Perhaps you want to update your question with the details of the last days. By the current state of the question I would assume (like *JaromandaX*) you missed to create a [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) from your router `publicIP:3306` to the server `privetIP:3306`. This has to be done at the router. // By the way, this is *NOT* [port-triggering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_triggering).

Comment: They told me since it's not possible to ping my desktop PC the problem is not in my home router. It seems there is something blocking the connection prior to that.

Comment: It depends: The router at the server side can be configured not to answer a ping (so pretending being not connected) in the hope to prevent a hacker's port scan and attack. Such port scans are the reason, why I'm not happy that you expose a widely known standard application port to the internet. But that can be managed later.